# How to reference a Windows Runtime Component that references a nuget package?

Tags: visual-studio, windows-runtime, nuget, win-universal-app, microsoft-band

I'm trying to use the Microsoft Band SDK from a UWP JavaScript app, but since it is only available as a Nuget package I'm trying to create a Windows Runtime Component that allows me to call certain methods from the Band SDK from my app.

I have been able to successfully create and build a Runtime Component in C# that references the Microsoft.Band Nuget package, and I have referenced it from my JS app. The app is build and deployed correctly, however I hit a runtime error when I try to call the methods from my component:

```
Exception is about to be caught by JavaScript library code at line 26, column 8 in ms-appx://7c21d66f-b8e1-486b-94af-eec2bcef9a13/js/default.js

0x80070002 - JavaScript runtime error: The system cannot find the file specified.



System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Band, Version=1.3.20420.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=608d7da3159f502b' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

   at System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime.ManagedActivationFactory.ActivateInstance()

WinRT information: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Band, Version=1.3.20420.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=608d7da3159f502b' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

   at System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime.ManagedActivationFactory.ActivateInstance()

If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.
```

Seems like the app is unable to find the Nuget package, even if it is referenced by the Runtime Component. Did I miss any step? Do I have to specify the dependency somewhere else? I wasn't able to find any information about this scenario in the documentation.

Comment: A NuGet package is only used during the build process - to get the required dlls for your project to compile. You would need to make sure that the referenced dll is available in your runtime (just like any of your custom dlls)

Comment: @hsirah And how am I supposed to include those dll, if Microsoft only distributes the Nuget package?

Comment: Did you solve the problem @ArcadioGarcia? I have the same issue with MQTTnet package. The dll files are in my %user%\.nuget\packages\mqttnet\2.5.1\lib\uap10.0 folder and it seems they are not deployed within the UWP application.

Comment: @AndreyKlochkov Sorry, I never managed to solve it